# How Do I Apply a Style Only When It Falls in an IFrame?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm trying to hide certain elements of the content displayed in an IFrame based on it falling within an IFrame tag.  I have control over the CSS for both the base page and the page to be displayed in the IFrame (they do run on different domains).  I would think that I should be able to define a stylesheet rule in the IFrame content's HTML that applies only when the element like the below example, but it doesn't work.  Is this possible and if so, what am I doing wrong?

```
<style>
iframe div.header
{
    display:none;

}
</style>
```

EDIT:  To clarify, I'm trying to apply a style only when the page is in an iFrame.  The main issue is that when we display content from one of our sites within another site I want the headers and footers to be hidden.  It would be logical to me that I apply the above style to accomplish that goal.  Why I can't write a CSS rule that only applies to elements that fall within an iFrame (that rule can be in either file as long as it works)?  I've tried that rule in both the main page and in the iframe content page.

Comment: Stuff in an `iframe` is a different document. I'd consider either giving your documents' bodies different stylesheets or replacing `iframe` with `div`.

Comment: Is there a CSS solution if I have total control of both pages?  I simply need to apply a rule only if the page being rendered is being rendered in an iFrame.

Comment: No, they are different documents. I think michael gave you the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest you can get is using Javascript within the iFrame to check if the current document is the root document.

If it is then ignore, if not then apply a class to the body

Comment: Unfortunately this may be the only solution.  We're going to try it and hope it doesn't result in any odd flashing or jumping pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change/control pages that on other domains. See [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) for more details.

Also, applying the style like this wouldn't work even if they were on the same domain b/c the content in the iframe is rendered independently from the parent page.

If you have access to both pages, why not put that style on the page that is displayed in the iframe?

Comment: I have placed that style in the page being displayed in the iframe and  that style is not applied.

Comment: Take off the iframe part of the style definition. It should just be: div.header {display:none;}

Comment: That will only make the div always invisible and not solve my problem.

Comment: In that case, I'd would add a query string to the url when you load the page in the iframe and have the page check if there is a query string and do all your style changes that way.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing a rule for the iFrame size, the same as you would for a mobile device:

```
@media (width: 500px) and (height: 350px) {
    .header{visibility:hidden}
}
```

If the iFrame is 500px wide and 350 px high.

The only thing is that I am not sure what the implications to a mobile device would then be...
However I have just tried it on a site and it works.